# Apply function to each groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function to each segment/partition that is the result of a groupby operation.

```
def get_click_rate(data):
    click_count = data[data['event'] == 'click'].shape[0]
    view_count = data[data['event'] == 'pageview'].shape[0]
    return click_count / view_count

data.groupby('linkid').apply(get_click_rate).reset_index(name='click rate')
```

The idea here is that I'm grouping the dataframe by `LinkID` of a webpage, and then each partition I'm passing to a function that filters the sub-dataframe, computes a number and returns it. However it returns wrong figures. Here is the snippet that returns the right figures

```
click_event = data[data['event'] == 'click'].groupby('linkid')['event'].count().reset_index(name='click count')
view_event = data[data['event'] == 'pageview'].groupby('linkid')['event'].count().reset_index(name='view count')
merged_df = pd.merge(left=click_event, right=view_event, on='linkid', how='inner')
merged_df['click rate'] = merged_df['click count'] / merged_df['view count']
```

To my eyes at least, they are doing the same things but in a different order, the second snippet filters the data first, groups it, and then merges the sub-dataframes to reach the desired figures.

Can someone help shed some light on what I'm missing here?

Comment: please provide some example data and the output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your `get_click_rate` function here and it seems to be returning the same result as the second approach you've written. The only problem I've encountered with `get_click_rate`  is when you try to compute the click rate for a `linkid` group that has no `'pageview'` event. Because of that, I've made some minor changes to your `get_click_rate` function:

```py
import pandas as pd


def get_click_rate(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """Calculate the click rate for a given ``linkid`` group.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : pd.DataFrame
        A dataframe representing values from a given ``linkid`` group,
        containing the column 'event'.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.Series
        A series containing the click count, view count, and click rate.
        The click rate is calculated as the ratio of the click count to
        the view counts. If the view count is zero, click rate gets set to zero.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    >>>     {'event': ['click', 'pageview', 'click', 'some_other_value'],
    >>>              'linkid': [1, 1, 2, 2]}
    >>> )
    >>> df.groupby('linkid').apply(get_click_rate).reset_index()
       linkid  click count  view count  click_rate
    0       1          1.0         1.0         1.0
    1       2          1.0         0.0         0.0

    Notes
    -----
    This function returns a pandas Series regardless of whether the
    ``linkid`` group contains any view count or not. Therefore, if you want
    only the ``linkid``s' that have click rates, you can use the following code:

    .. code-block:: python

        (
            df.groupby('linkid')
            .apply(get_click_rate)
            .reset_index()
            .loc[lambda xdf: xdf['click_rate'] > 0, :]
        )

    """

    click_count: int = data[data['event'] == 'click'].shape[0]
    view_count: int = data[data['event'] == 'pageview'].shape[0]
    click_rate: float = 0

    # Only compute the click rate when `view_count` is greater than zero.
    if view_count > 0:
        click_rate = round(click_count / view_count, 2)

    return pd.Series({'click count': click_count,
                      'view count': view_count,
                      'click_rate': click_rate})
```

### Testing `get_click_rate` Function

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def get_click_rate(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """Calculate the click rate for a given ``linkid`` group.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : pd.DataFrame
        A dataframe representing values from a given ``linkid`` group,
        containing the column 'event'.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.Series
        A series containing the click count, view count, and click rate.
        The click rate is calculated as the ratio of the click count to
        the view counts. If the view count is zero, click rate gets set to zero.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    >>>     {'event': ['click', 'pageview', 'click', 'some_other_value'],
    >>>              'linkid': [1, 1, 2, 2]}
    >>> )
    >>> df.groupby('linkid').apply(get_click_rate).reset_index()
       linkid  click count  view count  click_rate
    0       1          1.0         1.0         1.0
    1       2          1.0         0.0         0.0

    Notes
    -----
    This function returns a pandas Series regardless of whether the
    ``linkid`` group contains any view count or not. Therefore, if you want
    only the ``linkid``s' that have click rates, you can use the following code:

    .. code-block:: python

        (
            df.groupby('linkid')
            .apply(get_click_rate)
            .reset_index()
            .loc[lambda xdf: xdf['click_rate'] > 0, :]
        )

    """

    click_count: int = data[data['event'] == 'click'].shape[0]
    view_count: int = data[data['event'] == 'pageview'].shape[0]
    click_rate: float = 0

    # Only compute the click rate when `view_count` is greater than zero.
    if view_count > 0:
        click_rate = round(click_count / view_count, 2)

    return pd.Series({'click count': click_count,
                      'view count': view_count,
                      'click_rate': click_rate})


event_choices = ['click', 'pageview', 'some_other_value']
linkid_choices = ['1', '2', '3']
nrows = 30

# -- Generating a Dummy DataFrame for Testing ------------------------------
df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'event': np.random.choice(event_choices, nrows),
                'linkid': np.random.choice(linkid_choices, nrows),
            }
        ),
        pd.DataFrame({'event': ['some_other_value'] * 3, 'linkid': '4'})
    ], ignore_index=True
)


(
    # Group dataframe by column `linkid`
    df.groupby('linkid')
    # Apply function `get_click_rate` that returns a pandas Series with three
    # columns ('click count', 'view count' and 'click_rate') for every 'linkid' value.
    .apply(get_click_rate)
    .reset_index()
    # Convert the data type of 'click count', and 'view count' column to integers
    .astype({'click count': int, 'view count': int})
    # Filter for `linkid`s' that have a click rate greater than zero.
    .loc[lambda xdf: xdf['click_rate'] > 0, :]
)
# Returns:
#
#   linkid  click count  view count  click_rate
# 0      1            2           3        0.67
# 1      2            3           3        1.00
# 2      3            3           6        0.50
```

**Output:**

[image: Result of the get_click_rate function]